# Google Token Authentication with node.js and express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-signin

I have a node.js/express webservice that I would like to use to verify Google token coming from a mobile app.

From this tutorial (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) I learned that I have to make such a call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123
```

So I came up with this in my code:

```
var request = require('request');

module.exports = function(app) {

app.get('/authenticate', function(req, res) {

    request('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    })
});
};
```

Then, based on the response from google api, I would like to return true or false.

But it doesn't work. When I put "https://www.google.com" in the request, body is printed in the console, but the request is still being executed for some time.

What am I missing here? Is is the correct approach to the problem I described or should I do it in a completely different way?

Comment: Have this issue fixed ??

Comment: Yes, I think that I didn't set the Content-type application/json for the request.

Answer (score -1):

You need to send a response to your incoming HTTP request.

Call `res.send(...)`.

For more information, see the Express documentation.